# removing lines from command line awk

Tags: awk

i am finally able to get my awk scripts working but the issue I'm having is its displaying extra information, so I'm not understanding or missing a command. i just need to figure out what I'm not doing

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create awk script that will output the given data in the format given in word document
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," }

/./ {
##comment check if the third field is online, if print online
if ($3 == "online")
printf("%s is an online student\n", $1)

##commentcheck if the third field is onsite, if print onsite
if ($3 == "onsite")
printf("%s is an onsite student\n", $1)
} $1

#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create an awk script that will output the names of the students with a score that is higher than 75.
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," } NR > 1 {
    if ($2 >= 90 && $2 <= 100)
        grade = "A";
    else if ($2 >= 80 && $2 <= 89)
        grade = "B";
    else if ($2 >= 70 && $2 <= 79)
        grade = "C";
    else if ($2 >= 60 && $2 <= 69)
        grade = "D";
    else
        grade = "E";
    print $1, grade;
} $filename

#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create an awk script to read the provided data file and print the Name field from each line where the section is online
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," }

/./ {
##comment check if the section is online, if so print the name

if ($3 == "online")
print $1
} $1

#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create Write an awk script that will take the following data file and return the sum of each record.
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," }

/./ {
##comment initialize the total variable as 0
total=0

##comment loop all the intergers delimited by commas and add it to the
##comment variable total
##comment here NF represents number of fields present in a record

for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
total += $i

##comment post adding all the integers, print to console
print total
} $1
```

Comment: Please elaborate some more where it succeeds, where it fails, what you put in (example data) and what output you expect. Please make sure that your questions do not reference to each other, but that each question is a problem of its own that can be understood and followed without knowledge of your other activity here.

Comment: You have at least 4 awk scripts in your question. Pick one that exhibits the problem you need help with and shows us just THAT script along with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrate your problem so we can copy/paste to test with that.

Comment: i apologize, i believe i was having the same issue so i included them, I'm a n00b so pls forgive, wont happen again